# Benifits of having interfaces for services in Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, service, interface, ejb

Is it a good (and common) practice to have interfaces for each of the services in Java EE? What other benifits are there other than having the interface to specify what methods have to be implemented by a service?

An example:

```
public interface UserService {
     public User findUser(String username, String password);
}

@Stateless
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    public User findUser(String username, String password) {
        // some code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you intend to share the interfaces in a form of some client lib or API, then don't use them. There is no point in using them within a single module. Latest Java EE version emphasise simple, no-boilerplate code - the less code the better. Notable exceptions is CDI alternatives, but that is a special use case, very different from the ,,old java ee'' pattern of interface-impl.
The only exception in my opinion are JAXRS endpoint definitions if you have java based clients. Then it is useful to put Rest interfaces and DTOs into API module and share it between client and backend service provider(think microservices communication, or frontend-backend). But if your client is not java, don't bother with it and just annotate the bean itself.

Comment: When you're in the same module you can use the interfaces to define two ways of using the servicen but in this case you will have two interfaces.

Comment: Does that mean, if I take OP's example, if I have an EAR with a standard single ejb module + war module, I can directly inject UserServiceImpl defined in the ejb module in the war module with `@EJB`?

Comment: @Al1 Yes you can (at least in JEE7) and please don't name your EJBs `SomeServiceImpl` - just `SomeService`. Honestly the codebase of any modern Java EE app looks great, especially when you compare it with the mess it used to be.